# Hexagonal socket for 6-32 screws

Tags: pc

Can you recommend hexagonal socket (with 1/2 square or 1/4 hexagonal fixation) for 6-32 screws (standard PC screws) ? In particularm which size is needed ? 5.5mm or 6mm or what ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty much 'one of everything' for $£€ 15, such as this - [Fairly random Amazon search result for '"socket set computer"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Precision-Screwdriver-Faireach-Professional-Electronic/dp/B07MQ7VGX2?crid=2AOMJRMR279D1&keywords=socket+set+computer&qid=1667041599&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIyLjI4IiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=socket+set+computer%2Caps%2C81&sr=8-10)

[image]

They tend to not be very high spec, but you never need much force, so they're fine. I wouldn't recommend this kind of price point for heavy-duty work, but for light duty, computer work, most of it will last years.

Comment: @Soleil I have a very similar set to that pictured. It's fine for small computer screws such as 6-32. I also have a ½" drive socket set. It would be far too large and unwieldy for a 6-32. It would be very easy to apply too much torque and shear off a small screw.